# Suscribe to LMS published from an LWC in other package namespace

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, namespace, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

In a Managed Package, am publishing a message using a Lightning Message Channel in a Lightning Web Component.

I want to be able to suscribe to this Lightning Message Channel from a Lightning Web Component which is part of an extension package, installed on top of the main one.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieved this by adding this in the lwc of the extension package:

```
import messageChannelExample from '@salesforce/messageChannel/corenamespace__messageChannelExample __c';
```

and using it normally